# I am unable to install Google chrome via Ubuntu software centre

Tags: 11.10, google-chrome

i downloaded a stable version of Google Chrome. A .deb file got downloaded (i386). When I double click on it, Ubuntu software centre opens up and tries to install. But everytime an error pops up-

Internal Error .The file (/path to chrome) cannot be opened.

I have tried many methods but this just won't go. I don't think that the file is corrupted because this is the third time I have downloaded it.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Run `cd Downloads;sudo dpkg -i google-chrome*.deb` in a Terminal window, and post the output here.

Comment: neph@ubuntu:~$ cd Downloads;sudo dpkg -i google-chrome*.deb
[sudo] password for neph: 
Selecting previously deselected package google-chrome-stable.
(Reading database ... 125666 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking google-chrome-stable (from google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb) ...

Comment: dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of google-chrome-stable:
 google-chrome-stable depends on libnss3-1d (>= 3.12.3); however:
  Package libnss3-1d is not installed.
dpkg: error processing google-chrome-stable (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 google-chrome-stable
neph@ubuntu:~/Downloads$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are getting this error because a package the Google Chrome depends on to run is not installed. Run `sudo apt-get install -f` to fix this. You should then be able to run Google Chrome.

Comment: LOL should have tried that earlier. Thanks Aaron :)

Comment: You're welcome :) If you are satisfied with my answer, click the check mark next to it. This lets people know that you have found an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Try to edit your sources.list file by adding this line :

```
 deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
```

Then  update your system:

```
 apt-get update
```

And install google chrome normally :

```
apt-get install google-chrome-stable
```